# Editing C file with python using fileinput

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script in python2 that edits a C file

the part of the C file is  `unsigned char *commServer[] = {"2.2.2.2:1111"};`

In the python script i want to to be something like

```
IP = raw_input("Enter Your server IP: ")
port = raw_input("Enter Your Port: ")
```

then i want it to put the Server ip were it says 2.2.2.2 and it to put the port into were it says 1111

Comment: Please show least of your efforts.

Comment: After the user has entered the ip and the port, you can just open the c-file in python and change the line... (see https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)

Comment: Python2 will be discontinued soon. Please keep that in mind when creating new software with it.